# zfs recovery after hardware failure

Tags: storage, storage-area-network, zfs

My ZFS storage hardware failed including the rpool disks. I installed a new server and tried to import use `zfs import -f poolname`. I am able to see the pool and the disk utilized. But I am not able to see the volume. Is there is any way to recover the volumes? I have around 13 TB of important data on them.

**Details are**:

- OS:

  `OpenIndiana oi_151a9`
- `zpool status -v` output:

  ```
    pool: test
   state: ONLINE
    scan: none requested
  config:

          NAME                      STATE    READ WRITE CKSUM
          test                      ONLINE      0     0     0
            c13t50000394A8C9703Ad0  ONLINE      0     0     0
            c15t50000394A8C96436d0  ONLINE      0     0     0
            c16t50000394A8C9714Ad0  ONLINE      0     0     0
            c17t50000394A8C97122d0  ONLINE      0     0     0
  ```
- `zpool list` output:

  ```
  NAME    SIZE  ALLOC    FREE   EXPANDSZ  CAP  DEDUP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
  rpool1   37G  14.3G   22.7G   -         38%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
  test   14.5T  2.25T   12.3T   -         15%  1.00x  ONLINE  -
  ```
- `zfs list` output:

  ```
  NAME        USED   AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
  rpool1     22.6G   13.8G    46K  /rpool1
  sas4tb-5    369G   3.57T    31K  /sas4tb-5
  test       2.25T   12.0T  2.25T  /test 
  ...
  ```

Motherboard, and the DOM on which the installation has been done failed. So we put the disks on another server and installed openindiana again. Than we execute the command `zfs import -f test` with which we got our pool back. But the volume are not imported.

Name of the pool is test and sas4tb-5. We are searching for the zvol and expected to see the data in the volumes.

Comment: Please post your `zpool status -v` `zpool list` and `zfs list`.

Comment: Also information about your ZFS implementation, OS, distribution, version...

Comment: How did the hardware "fail"? I'm sorry, there is too little information here to help you. What was the name of the pool? Are you searching for a filesystem or a zvol? What do you expect to see?

Comment: @user1365171 Please use the edit link to edit your question when providing more info